# How to convert viewstate "object" to dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, casting, viewstate

I got an embarrassing problem with the code below.

In the first method (the on-load one) I attempt to transfer the dictionary I've stored in the viewstate into the variable "dict".

I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type "object" to Dictionary".

I've tired typecasting with no success. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

PS(Reason why I'm using viewstate to begin with is that the selection from the listbox below disappears when the page reloads)

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //throws the implicit conversion error
    if (ViewState["dict"] != null) {
        dict = ViewState["dict"];
        //dict = (Dictionary<string, int>)ViewState["dict"];
    }


    Response.Write("Reload");
    foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items) {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(li.Value)) {
            if (dict[li.Value] == 3) {
                li.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: green;");
                Label3Items.Text += "<br>" + li.Text;
            }
            else if (dict[li.Value] == 2) {
                li.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: blue;");
                Label2Items.Text += "<br>" + li.Text;
            }
            else if (dict[li.Value] == 1) {
                li.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: yellow;");
                Label1Items.Text += "<br>" + li.Text;
            }
            else {
                li.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: red;");
                LabelVetoItems.Text += "<br>" + li.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void updateName(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Welcome "+TextBox1.Text+"!";
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Updater(3);
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Updater(2);
}
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Updater(1);
}
protected void ButtonVeto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Updater(0);
}

protected void Updater(int indexer) {

    //loops through listitems, color-marks selected items and stores to dictionary
    foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items) {
        if (li.Selected == true) {
            //li.Enabled = false;
            if (indexer == 3) {
                li.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: green;");
                Label3Items.Text += "<br>" + li.Text;
                dict.Add(li.Value, 3);
            }
            else if (indexer == 2) {
                li.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: blue;");
                Label2Items.Text += "<br>" + li.Text;
                dict.Add(li.Value, 2);
            }
            else if (indexer == 1) {
                li.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: yellow;");
                Label1Items.Text += "<br>" + li.Text;
                dict.Add(li.Value, 1);
            }
            else{
                li.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: red;");
                LabelVetoItems.Text += "<br>" + li.Text;
                dict.Add(li.Value, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    //stores the dictionary with updates key-pair objects from user selection
    ViewState["dict"] = dict;

}

protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
//unfinished
}
}
```

Comment: How exactly did you try to cast it?

Comment: The added in a comment the syntax I used. I still a get squiggly red line.

Comment: So what is the error when you try to cast like this?

Comment: The error was "Cannot implicitly convert type "object" to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary" and I double-checked that the syntax is correct. Could it be that dictionary isn't serialized?

Comment: Alright, apparently it was an error in VS. I updated with an answer before as to not confuse anyone else. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I saved my project and reopened it and now the error is gone and the app works. Apparently, the syntax was correct but it was a problem with VS.

Sorry about this, should have double-checked it wasn't an IDE error. 
I've never had VS act weird like this before!